# how to implement stp, rstp , mstp protocol using scapy?

Tags: scapy, stp

I am trying to implement the SPANNING TREE PROTOCOL, rapid spanning tree protocol and multiple spanning tree protocol using SCAPY. Can someone post the code to implement the same .

Comment: You should post what you've tried so far and the problems you're having. In particular any code you've written to date. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It’s not currently implemented, meaning that you must implement it yourself.

You can have a look on internet if someone has already done it and lookup through scapy source code

Also, see
[Adding new protocols](http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_dissect.html) from scapy’s documentation

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I get it. But to such a wide question, I can only bring up wide answers.